# Model predictive control

Tags: matlab, optimization, controls, simulink, prediction

Hi I try to define a model predictive controller and I can't get it to function correctly.
I am currently using the Matlab function nlmpc and implementing it into Simulink using the Nonlinear mpc block.

I found this documentation from Matlab
https://se.mathworks.com/help/mpc/ug/optimization-problem.html#bujxvp9-9

Where I want to use the alternative cost function Can anyone help me how to specify that?
I tried defining my own custom function (without any luck).

```
nlobj = nlmpc(nx,ny,nu); 
nlobj.Ts                           = Ts_mpc;
nlobj.PredictionHorizon            = N;
nlobj.ControlHorizon               = Nc;
nlobj.Model.IsContinuousTime       = false;
nlobj.Model.StateFcn               = @MPC_state_function;
nlobj.Optimization.CustomCostFcn   = @Cost_function;
nlobj.Optimization.ReplaceStandardCost          = true;

nlobj.Weights.OutputVariables      = [10 8 2 5 1 9 4];
nlobj.Weights.ManipulatedVariables = [.1 .1];
```

Where the custom cost function is `J = x_e'*Q*x_e + u_e'*R*u_e;`

Alternatively, I would like other suggestions on how to use nonlinear mpc in simulink (other than ACADO)

best regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

nlobj.Optimization.ReplaceStandardCost          = true;

nlobj.Optimization.CustomCostFcn   = 'Alternative Cost Function';

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).